# WaveSurfer.create is not a function

Tags: next.js, wavesurfer.js

i'm trying to add WaveSurfer.js to Next.js app.

I imported package by next/dynamic like this

```
const WaveSurfer = dynamic(() => import('wavesurfer.js'), {ssr: false})
```

and now when i trying to create new player by WaveSufer.create() i'm getting info that **WaveSurfer.create is not a function**.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Unfortunately not, i tried to import it like this const WaveSurfer = dynamic(() => { return import('wavesurfer.js') }, {ssr: false}) but when i tried use it i'm getting WaveSurfer.create is not a function.

Comment: Got here looking for how to do this with Svelte. Here is the solution. https://svelte.dev/repl/1364dc8356fb4c30b875dbc888ca3e82?version=3.57.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead dynamic import wavesurfer.js i should import a component where wavesurfer.js is used.

```
const DynamicComponent = dynamic(
    () => import('../Waveform/Waveform'),
    {ssr: false}
)
```

and then use it as regular component f.ex.

```
<StyledContainer>
   <DynamicComponent/>
</StyledContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be fixed by importing wavesurfer like this:

```
 const WaveSurfer = (await import("wavesurfer.js")).default;
```